# Facebook Graph API: Resume Session on iPhone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

I have been playing with the Facebook Graph API since yesterday and it is pretty good, however, I have been searching around the web for some method of resuming a session. That is, once a user has gone through the authentication (of allowing an app to use their data), logging in automatically when they open the app (or even providing a login button).

I have found plenty of posts on FBSession and using [session resume]. The problem is, these have been removed. What is the new method of resuming a users session and logging in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After succesfully logging in your Facebook object will have the token values in

```
[Facebook accessToken]
[Facebook expirationDate]
```

Save these values (I recommend `NSUserDefaults`).

The next time the app starts, restore them with

```
Facebook.accessToken = savedAccessToken;
Facebook.expirationDate= savedExpirationDate;
```

Then is `[Facebook isAuthorized]` to verify if the token is still valid, if it is, you can consider yourself logged in.

Answer (score 0):

My application using below API has past session after once authed.
It should be reference to learn how to do it.

http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2